# Best Practice: How to restrict access to Communities in Sandbox environments?

Tags: community, bestpractice, access

We have this scenario: We have multiple sandbox environments that are used to develop and customize communities. Some communities include a public section.

Some of these sandbox communities are functionally equal to production (incl. self-registration, etc.) and used by our business users for functional, UX or UAT testing.

We used to restrict access to these sandbox communities via IP ranges, limited to various company/service provider IP ranges.

However during the current Corona pandemic most people switched to working from home. Many of these people (especially from smaller companies) do not work in the sandboxes using a company VPN connection but using their personal internet provider. This needs to be possible in the future too.
Unfortunately this removes the "IP" criterium as an option to restrict access to the sandbox communities.

So, my question is: How do other's handle this? Can you point me into some directions?

What I've considered so far but all determined as not workable:

1. Disable self-registration in some environments to at least protect the non-public parts
2. Set all pages to non-public (in combination with item 1)
3. Disable community during adaption and re-enable when testing